# index out of range when trying to use substring

Tags: java

I made a simple program to spell-check words. The program has 2 inputs, an array of String that works as a dictionary and a String that is a sentence. The program checks the sentence (word to word) and checks the dictionary to find a simmilar word, then it asks the user if they meant to write the word in the dictionary.

Requirements:
The first 2 characters need to be the same.
The word in the dictionary can only have 2 more characters than the sentence word.
The word in the dictionary can only have 2 different characters than the word in the sentence. (The only characters that count are the ones with index between 0 and the length of the sentence word. E.g. efg and egg|s)

```
public static String SpellCheck(String[] dictionary, String sentence){
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String newSentence = "";
        StringTokenizer divisor = new StringTokenizer(sentence);
        while(divisor.hasMoreElements()){
            String word = divisor.nextToken();
            String a = "";
            for(int i = 0; i<dictionary.length; ++i){
                int n  = 0;
                if(word.length()>2 && dictionary[i].length()-word.length()<=2 && word.substring(0,2).indexOf(dictionary[i].substring(0,2))==0){
                    String s1 = word.substring(2,word.length());
                    String s2 = dictionary[i].substring(2,dictionary[i].length());
                    for(int k = 0; k<s1.length(); ++k){
                        String l1 = s1.substring(k,k+1);
                        String l2 = s2.substring(k,k+1);
                        if(l1.indexOf(l2)!=0)++n;
                    }
                    if(n<=2){
                        System.out.print(dictionary[i] + "?");
                        a = sc.nextLine();
                        if("yes".indexOf(a)==0){
                            newSentence += dictionary[i] + " ";
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }  
            }
            if("yes".indexOf(a)!=0)newSentence += word + " ";
        }
        return newSentence;
    }
```

The problem is at the line

```
String s2 = dictionary[i].substring(2,dictionary[i].length());
```

It works for the first word in the sentence but in the second time I get an error saying "String index is out of range" and I can't figure out why since I'm using .length() to find the index of the last letter. I hope someone can help me figuring out what's wrong with this program. Thank you!

Comment: By the way StringTokenizer is a legacy class. You should be using String.split() instead.

Comment: Why the `substring(2` whats with the first 2 characters? Or are you trying to find some other word that has the same first 2 starting characters ?

Comment: The first 2 characters need to be the same, it's one of the requirements.

Comment: What input/dictionary are you using ? Seems to be working for a small test i have made. [Take a look at it here](https://ideone.com/1wyGM6)

Comment: So, debug it and you will see why: `System.out.println(dictionary[i].length());`

Comment: Your code won't work if the dictionary has words with less than 2 characters. That's because `substring(0,2)` will throw `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException` if the `string` in the dictionary doesn't have 2 characters at least

Comment: also i'd add a `System.out.println(dictionary[i]);` to see which string in the dictionary it breaks at

Comment: The input I put in my question is the one that doesn't work for those who were asking,

Comment: @RyanTurnbull I already found out where it breaks, it's the second word I check.

Comment: @Isac I already changed that and still have the same problem. The input is after the code in the original question.

Comment: You need to set up a verifiable example. What exact `sentence` and `dictionary` are you using? And if are using a code that is different from the question, update the question so that we can test and see the problem.

Comment: @Isac String[] dicionario1 = new String[]{"interessa", "interessar", "interessante", "discipulo", "disciplinar", "disciplina", "estamos", "estar", "este", "esta"};
 String frase = "esda disciplima é muito intesessan";

Comment: @Isac What I said was that the example was in the question, not that I changed the code. xD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your error is in the for loop just below where you've said the error is

```
String s2 = dictionary[i].substring(2,dictionary[i].length());

for(int k = 0; k<s1.length(); ++k){ //HERE
    String l1 = s1.substring(k,k+1);
    String l2 = s2.substring(k,k+1);
}
```

When setting l1 and l2, you will be exceeding the bounds of your string index. the for loop should read

```
for(int k = 0; k < s1.length()-1; ++k){
```

Answer (score 0):

What if the length is less than 2? Your starting index is 2.

Comment: That's true but not the problem, the word I'm checking has 8 letters. Anyways, thank you for the advice I'm going to change that aswell!

Comment: @mike the problem isn't so much with the word you're checking; what if the **dictionary** word is one character long? Then you're doing `.substring(2,1)`.